# Files in python are empty for no reason

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, file-io, pygame

I have tried to split up my world generation from my actual game, since I usually fail with it. But for some reason it keeps insisting the file is empty/ the variable gained from it is empty, and sometimes, when I look afterwards, the actual program file has emptied the text file with all the info, sometimes not. Here is the code:

[Dropbox Main code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3tab11mkmbe2xi/PlatformerGame)

[Dropbox World gen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/giv63jf1rpukj2h/World%20Generator.py)

Here's a small extract of just the file handling in the main code:

```
world_file = open("C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Python Files\PlatformerGame Files\World.txt", "r")
world_file_contents = world_file.read()
world_file.close()
world_file_contents = world_file_contents.split("\n")
WORLD = []
for data in world_file_contents:
    usable_data = data.split(":")
    WORLD.append(Tile(usable_data[0],usable_data[1]))
```

And the tile class:

```
class Tile():
    def __init__(self,location,surface):
        self.location = location
        self.surface = surface
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Python Files\PlatformerGame", line 89, in <module>
    Game.__main__()
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Python Files\PlatformerGame", line 42, in __main__
    WORLD.append(Tile(usable_data[0],usable_data[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Sorry if it's obvious. Also I'm using pygame.

Comment: Are you sure every line in your file has a colon ":" ? Or maybe you have a trailing blank line at the end.

Comment: Yep, that's part of the answer, thanks! But it still doesn't explain why using os.startfile on the gen just empties the file, while manually running the gen and removing the os code works fine. Submit your answer, I'll accept that as a right answer.

Comment: I guess there probably *is* a reason the files are empty after all.

Comment: @BenHack: Why use `os.startfile()` *at all*? Why not just import that file? You are probably running into a race condition; where the file has been emptied but the new data hasn't been written yet when your game opens the file.

Comment: Wait a minute, you're lauching your other Python script with `os.startfile`? I hadn't read the main source code... As @kindall says, that _must_ be the reason. You're executing code asynchronously, while you should simply import it to run it within the same Python thread.

Comment: Now the tile blitting claims it's blitting in a invalid location. I have never used importing from other files, os.startfile was the first similar thing I had found like it. I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have empty lines in your input file; you would want to skip these.

You can also simplify your tile reading code:

```
with open("C:\Users\Ben\Documents\Python Files\PlatformerGame Files\World.txt", "r") as world_file:
    WORLD = [Tile(*line.strip().split(":", 1)) for line in world_file if ':' in line]
```

This only processes lines if there is a `:` character in them, splits only once, and creates the `WORLD` list in one loop.

As for using `os.startfile()`: you are starting the other script in the background. That script then opens the file to write to and explictly empties the file, before it generates new data. **At the same time** you are trying to read from that file. Chances are you end up reading an empty file at that time, as the other process hasn't yet *finished* generating and writing the data, and as file writes are buffered you won't see *all* of the data until the other process closes the file and exits.

Don't use `os.startfile()` *at all* here. Import the other file instead; then the code will be executed *during* import and the file is guaranteed to be closed.