# Pygame screen crashes without error report

Tags: python, python-2.7, crash, screen, pygame

I have two files, one to generate a world, and another to run the main code. However, the main screen keeps crashing  for no reason. I think the world gen may also be broken, but it does at least pass on valid data to the main code.

```
        # Main loop.
        while RUNNING:

            # Fill the screen.
            screen.fill((0,0,0))

            # Event handling.
            for eventa in event.get():
                if eventa.type == QUIT:
                    RUNNING = f
            screen.fill(SCREENCOLOR)

            # Draw the world.
            for tile in WORLD:
                if tile.surface == None:
                    pass
                else:
                    screen.blit(tile.surface,tile.location)

            # Draw the character
            screen.blit(PLAYER["image"],PLAYER["loc"])

            # Pygame commands clear up.
            clock.tick(FPS)
            screen.flip()
```

This code doesn't even fill the screen with white. This may just be too much data to handle, sorry if it is.

[World generator](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3tab11mkmbe2xi/PlatformerGame)

[Main code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3tab11mkmbe2xi/PlatformerGame)

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112886/files-in-python-are-empty-for-no-reason?noredirect=1#comment26520025_18112886)

Comment: I don't know where in this code it would be happening, but normally crashes without error reports are the result of infinite loops that never break or do anything.  Try putting `print("something")` at random points in the code and see how many it makes it to.  Your infinite loop will be between the last one printed and the next one.

Comment: Pygame is naturally infinite, but with pauses. I have put clock.tick, so it should work.

Comment: remember that the loop that is broken isn't necessarily the main loop.

Comment: there are no other while loops. All the for loops are before the screen gets set up in order to get frozen.

Comment: Maybe your install isn't the 32/64bit match for python that you installed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure that you aren't inserting too many things onto the screen. I believe that the problem is far more simple. You have said screen.flip() However, a surface object has no attribute called flip. You must be confused with the function pygame.display.flip() If you use this instead, the game shall display its visual output.